# Cannot use serialBluetooth functions even tough the plugin was installed

Tags: cordova-plugins, android-bluetooth

I cannot use the bluetoothSerial functions even though I installed the plugin by running cordova "plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" command in the project folder. I have received no errors and the plugin exists in the plugins folder.

I have tried adding plugin tag to the config.xml,

I have tried adding bluetooth permission to the AndroidManifest.xml

but none helped.

My cordova version is 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

```
    var app = {

      initialize: function()

    {

    this.bindEvents();

    },

      bindEvents: function () 

    {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready',this.onDeviceReady(), 
    false)},
      onDeviceReady: function () {

        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){

    console.log(event.touches);

          touchX = event.touches[0].pageX;

          touchY = event.touches[0].pageY;

          console.log(touchX, touchY);

          if (touchX <= button1.x + button1.width && touchX >= button1.x) 
    {
            if (touchY <= button1.y + button1.height && touchY >= 
    button1.y) {
                check = 1;  // Everything is fine until here. 
                bluetoothSerial.isEnabled(success(), fail()); // the code 
    here and below here is never executed. 
                c.font = "80px Arial";
                c.fillText("here",50,50);
        }
      }
```

When I debug using chrome://inspect/#devices I receive:

```
 serialBluetooth is not defined error.
```

why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it is necessary to include the script tag, cordova.js.